# Getting error while using webcam external javacript in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Getting error - Refused to apply style from  because its MIME type ('text/javascript') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

External javascript which I am trying to include is https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.26/webcam.js for accessing laptop's webcam.

Component-

```
<aura:component  implements="force:appHostable" access="global" >
    <ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.webcam}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
    <div id="my_camera" class="my_camera"></div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller-

```
scriptsLoaded : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log('success');  
        Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
 },
```

The same is working fine on the Visualforce page. When I directly use

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/webcamjs/1.0.26/webcam.js"/>
 <body>
   <apex:form >
      <div id="my_camera"></div>
   </apex:form>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
    Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
</script>
```

Comment: how are you including this in your project?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to provide the code that is producing this error?

Comment: @pchittum there are number of various applications that I need to build using the same. Also, my previous development in which I want to use this are lightning components.

Comment: @DavidReed I have added more things in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`<ltng:require>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ltng:require/documentation) incorrectly. You've placed your JavaScript static resource in the `styles` attribute

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.webcam}"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
```

but scripts go in the `scripts` attribute, as in this example from the Lightning Component Library linked above:

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require
        styles="{!$Resource.jsLibraries  + '/styles/jsMyStyles.css'}"
        scripts="{!$Resource.jsLibraries + '/jsLibOne.js'}"
        afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.scriptsLoaded}" />
</aura:component>
```